# error connect timed out when i am sending mail from php using send mail for wamp

Tags: php, sendmail

Hi I am trying to send mail from php but when i run the file i have got the error Connect timed out in the file error.log of send mail. this is my php code:

```
<?php
$message='<html><body><div align="center"><p> Bonjour c est l admin </p></div></body></html>';

if(mail('asmaaachemingui@gmail.com','Localhost subject',$message,'From: assoumasmaassoum@gmail.com')) 
    echo 'Email sent';
else
    echo 'sent failed';
?>
```

I didn't know how to solve this problem please help me

Comment: Did you install the mail server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail

Comment: Please provide more info like error logs and smtp configurations update.

Comment: You can also look into [hmailserver](https://www.hmailserver.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-function-doesnt-complete-sending-of-e-mail)

Comment: which mail server you are using ?

Comment: the error log was connect timed out

Comment: i am using sendmail with wamp

Comment: check it out the instructions here. http://yogeshchaugule.com/blog/2013/configure-sendmail-wamp

Comment: smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com # if gmail, if configured with stunnel use localhost
smtp_port=465 # if gmail, if configured with stunnel use 25
smtp_ssl=auto # if gmail, if configured with stunnel use none

Comment: i have not stunnel in my computer